# How to use Onchanged and OnTouch for the same boutton in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android application at my work and I am having a problem.

I need to know how I can use the `Onchanged` and `OnTouch` methods for the same button with conditions?

For example: If my button is on left than you can only touch it to do something and if it is on right than you can use it as a spinner.

Comment: You cannot use a button as a Spinner. It will throw ObjectCastException...But you can do both methods for the same Button.

Comment: Actually in my case its not really a button but an area ! And i just want to use these two methods on that area with conditions. I really don't know how to do it ?

Comment: You could add a flag and change it each time your button is changing sides.

Comment: I'm already using booleans in my application but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use an image Button for both the case. As your requirement, use image Button as a normal Button when in left-side and spinner when on right. You can make use of a variable "i" to be set if it is in right side. Change the method if it is reset.

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
     />
```

Then define your spinner in terms of what you need inside it. Like this may be....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/love"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/hem"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/love"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

In the mainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    addListenerToSpinnerButton();
}

private void addListenerToSpinnerButton(){
    spinnerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSpinner);
    spinnerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(p != null)
                showSpinner(MainActivity.this, p);
        }
    });
}
```